# NSOutlineView with 2 columns

Tags: cocoa, nsoutlineview

I have an NSOutlineView working.  So far so good.

Now I'm trying to add checkbox to each row and not having a lot of luck.

If I create a new column in position 0 and drag a checkbox control into it, I do get a checkbox control in the first column, but text no longer shows up in the 2nd column.  I have the 2nd column set as the outline column.

I get callbacks to populate the row's text for the checkbox column, but not for the text column (which is probably why there is no text in it) via:

```
-(id)outlineView:objectValueForTableColumn:byItem:
```

If I remove the checkbox column, everything goes back to working correctly.

Also, if I just remove the checkbox control from the column, then I get the callback asking for the text for the 2nd column.

What is it about adding the checkbox into the first column that is causing it to not has for text for the 2nd one?

It doesn't seem to matter if the checkbox is first or last, just having it in one of the columns keeps it from working.

If I add a Static Text control to the 2nd column, then the text shows up, but I no longer get callbacks to `-(id)outlineView:objectValueForTableColumn:byItem:` when the text is edited.

I also don't get any callbacks when the checkbox is clicked on, which is probably the same issue.

Not sure how to better explain this.  Here is a screen shot of how the view is set up:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to do this is to use a view based outline, and have the check box and the static text part of the same view.

[image: /Users/janicedelmar/Desktop/IB.tiff]

Comment: OK, doing that got the layout to work, but how do I set the text or set/read the checkboxes.  Sorry for the cocoa 101 questions, I'm really new to this and the NSOutlineView is not very well documented.